# Trying to find elements with named attributes

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find all elements in a node within a document containing specific attributes.

The node itself contains something like this

```
<chapter id="1561" parent="6542">
  <name>Quiz</name>
  <action id="5520" parent="1561" on="show">
    <name>on show hide nav_buttons</name>
    <actionitem actiontaken="hide" target="object" targetobject="5518">
    </actionitem>
  </action>
  <action id="5517" parent="1561" on="show">
    <name>on show reset test for resitting</name>
    <actionitem actiontaken="resettest" target="object" targetobject="1689">
    </actionitem>
  </action>
  <button id="5439" parent="1561" resource="5440" ontop="true" proportional="true" mouseoverimage="5442" clickedimage="5441">
    <name>start_quiz_button</name>
  </button>
  <image id="6549" parent="1561" resource="6550" visible="false" proportional="false">
    <name>Rectangle to hide text (if required)</name>
  </image>
</chapter>
```

I'm trying to find all elements with 'targetobject' or resource.  I'm using both

```
*[@targetobject]
*[@resource]
```

I get no hits for targetobject, but it finds resource.  If I use // then it works, but that gets all the matches in the Document.

I guess it's because the resource is on the first child level, but targetobject is not, so how can I do this just on the sub node I want?

Comment: What result are you exactly expecting? If you only want the elements with attribute targetobject in them from the node `chapter`. You can do `//chapter//*[@targetobject]`

Comment: What processor or you using and in which context are you? `*[@targetobject]` should give you two hits if you are the correct element. Otherwise you might want to use `//*[@targetobject]` or restrict it to some known parent element. By the way, you can also do `*[@targetobject or @resource]` to get both in one query.

Comment: This <chapter> element is one of many chapters inside a large document. What I am expecting is 2 hits for targetobject, but I get zero with *[@targetobject] when using the <chapter> node in my xpath evaluate statement.  If using // it finds all targetobject elements regardless of where they are in the document, i.e also in all other chapters and I don't know how to prevent that.  I have found using descendant::*[@targetobject] works to locate something in the particular chapter's descendants.